# Builder Pattern Using Spring Injected Resources

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, dependency-injection, builder

I have a *Builder* that uses several resources that are injected via Spring. It looks similar to this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SandBoxBuilder {
    private final SandUtil sandUtil;
    private Sand sand;
    private Box box;

    @Autowired
    public SandBoxBuilder(SandUtil sandUtil) {
        this.sandUtil = sandUtil;
    }

    public SandBoxBuilder setSand(Sand sand) {
        this.sand = sand;
        return this;
    }

    public SandBoxBuilder setBox(Box box) {
        this.box = box;
        return this;
    }

    public SandBox build() {
        SandBox sandBox = new SandBox(sand);
        sandUtil.changeBox(sandBox, box);
        return sandBox;
    }
}
```

The problem I have with this is that it is not thread safe. I know that this builder should not be a singleton, but I am not sure how to use the spring injected resources (`SandUtil`) without wiring the builder up and injecting it where I use it.

How can I implement a **thread safe** builder that utilizes singletons injected by spring?

### Solution

Because of some architectural constraints I could not inject the utilities into my calling classes. I ended up implementing a factory builder bean that returns new instances of a builder that has references to the spring resources.

**Solution Implementation**

```
@Component
public class SandBoxBuilderFactory {
    private final SandUtil sandUtil;

    @Autowired
    public SandBoxBuilderFactory(SandUtil sandUtil) {
        this.sandUtil = sandUtil;
    }

    public Builder newBuilder(){
        return new Builder(sandUtil);
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private final SandUtil sandUtil;
        private Sand sand;
        private Box box;

        private Builder(SandUtil sandUtil) {
            this.sandUtil = sandUtil;
        }

        public Builder setSand(Sand sand) {
            this.sand = sand;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setBox(Box box) {
            this.box = box;
            return this;
        }

        public SandBox build() {
            SandBox sandBox = new SandBox(sand);
            sandUtil.changeBox(sandBox, box);
            return sandBox;
        }

    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
newBuilder().setBox(box).setSand(sand).build();
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Instead I would have the `SandUtil` injected in the code that needs to use a `SandBoxBuilder` and pass it in as a constructor argument.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Unfortunately the constraints I am working with wont allow me to do that, the builder is autowired and "has" to stay that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your `SandBoxBuilder` as a bean because of `@Component`. Wherever you need it, you must have access to the `ApplicationContext`. I would propose, instead of injecting the `SandBoxBuilder` bean, inject the `SandUtil` bean and use it to create `SandBoxBuilder` instances

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final SandUtil sandUtil;

    @Autowired
    public MyService (SandUtil sandUtil) {
        this.sandUtil = sandUtil;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        SandBoxBuilder builder = new SandBoxBuilder(sandUtil);
        ... // use it
    }
}
```

Does `SandUtil` need to be a bean? It might fit as a `static` utility class.

Comment: Unfortunately there are constraints that prevent me from doing this. Although I did take a similar approach utilizing a static inner builder within the wired builder bean.

Comment: @MikeRylander Except for the name of the class and the fact that you return the build instead of using it, we've proposed the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about the Spring IOC lately. I use the Tapestry IOC alot which should provide similar inner working.

First of all a singleton should be thread-safe per definition. So if you create the builder every time you use it, the builder does not need to be thread-safe. The SandUtil must be in itself threadsafe.

It's like a contract: If you are a singleton service you are injected in multiple threads. Therefore a singleton service has to be threadsafe (synchronized methods, shared lock, synchronized objects and so on). If your service is PerThread meaning the same service is only used within a single thread, it has not to be thread safe.

So ensure SandUtil is threadsafe and you are fine if Sandbox is PerThread or PerOccurence (new instance is created every time it is injected).

If you want to make the builder threadsafe since you can not be sure a single instance of it is only used within a thread - and you do not care much about performance - you can just add synchronized keyword to every non-private method of the builder class. This is the poor-mans concurrency control otherwise check out some tutorials about concurrency control like the [original Java lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: The `@Component` by defaults create a singleton bean in the context, so it is not thread-safe here.

Comment: It is not thread safe because it holds state that is modified by every caller. I also am very concerned with performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the non-thread-safe part of this has to do with the sandUtil field?

You can use external locking on the changeBox method to ensure synchronized access to it.

Otherwise, perhaps the 'prototype' bean scope would help you out?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Comment: Locking would slow the system down to much for this use case.